# Javascript complicated append and updating DOM so it able to be removed with remove();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem, I am trying to remove an appended table row. Whenever the user clicks .removeRow, which activates the function removeCustomSetting()

The table row isn't removed after clicking the button. I think it is because the append function doesn't update the DOM.

I tried many things such as updating the DOM element, which wasn't an success.

If someone knows how to fix this, I would really appriciate that :)

Our table row

```
<tbody id="customSettingsTableContent">
    <tr id="settingRow_265"><td>ertert</td><td>17-03-2016&nbsp;19:19:59</td><td><a style="cursor:pointer;" class="removeRow" onclick="removeCustomSetting('265','p3rstuxgq7');"><li class="fa fa-close"></li></a></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Here we remove the row by id (like this `settingRow_265 )` in the table. Every ID is unique in the table, as it is pulled from an Auto increment in the database.

```
   function removeCustomSetting(settingId, inputId) {
    $.post("", { action: "removeCustomSetting", settingId: settingId, inputId: inputId },
        function(data,status){ 
            if(status=='success') { 

                $("#settingRow_" + settingId + "").remove(); 
                    var countCustomSettingRow = $('#customSettingsTable tr').length-1; 

                        if(countCustomSettingRow<1) { $("#customSettingsTableContent").html("<tr><td>No custom settings found...</td><td></td><td></td></tr>"); }

            } 
        }                                       
        );
    }
```

Here we add the row to the table after submitting and getting JSON data back.

```
      function addCustomSetting(inputId) {
            customSettingName = $('input[name=customSettingName]').val(); 
                if(!customSettingName) { alert("Can't be empty"); } else {
                    alert("OK "+ customSettingName +"");

                        $.post("", { action: "addCustomSetting", customSettingName: customSettingName, inputId: inputId },

                        function(data,status){ 

                            var return_addCustomSettingResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                        alert("success " + data + "");

                        $("#customSettingsTableContent").html("<tr><td>" + return_addCustomSettingResponse.name + "</td><td>" + return_addCustomSettingResponse.date + " " + return_addCustomSettingResponse.time + "</td><td>" + return_addCustomSettingResponse.inputId + "<a style=\"cursor:pointer;\" onclick=\"removeCustomSetting('" + return_addCustomSettingResponse.id + "','" + return_addCustomSettingResponse.inputId + "');\"><li class=\"fa fa-close\"></li></a></td></tr>");


                   }                                            
               );
           }
       }
```

Comment: Is it live somewhere?

Comment: What isn't working, exactly?

Comment: The table row isn't removed after clicking the button. I think it is because the append function doesn't update the DOM. - Sorry for not making it more clear.

Comment: There is a live demo, https://www.oasis-hosting.net/panel/  Log in with: email: support@oasis-hosting.net password: oasishosting - Go to one of the services by clicking manage and click the little plus at the module input     https://gyazo.com/7146da589867885318dde543d1ff6a5f and there it is.

Comment: what does append working have to do with removing something? I don't even see where you used .append.

Comment: I am adding rows to a table, and they and the rows have to displayed to the user.

Comment: and? what does that have to do with your problem? .remove works just fine for me.

Comment: If .remove isn't working for you, it's because you aren't selecting an element to remove. There's no other way for it to.. not work.

Comment: Whenever you add a new row, that row is not able to be removed because the DOM hasn't been updated. That is the problem I am facing, updating the DOM after prepending.

Comment: *"because the DOM hasn't been updated."* that makes no sense. If the dom hasn't been updated, there won't be a remove button to click to remove the row because the row doesn't exist!

Comment: Try it out yourself with the details provided above. Whenever you add a new row and directly try to remove the table row it will just not work.

Comment: Right, but that's not because the DOM isn't updated. It's because `$("#settingRow_" + settingId + "")` failed to reference an element, which would mean either the id is wrong in the html, or it is being passed to the function incorrectly. Your code looks fine as far as what you've presented.

Comment: Look here. You've failed to give the table row an ID `$("#customSettingsTableContent").html("<tr><td>" + return_a...` so when you attempt to select it by id later, you can't.

Comment: Just to make a point though... IF you were using regular event binding rather than the attribute onclick bs, you could have simply done `$(this).closest('tr').remove()`, but no, you've gotta do it by id because you're complicating things with `onclick` attributes..

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks, please post an "answer" so I can accept it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to give the table rows ID's in the way your sample html has.

```
$("#customSettingsTableContent").html("<tr><td>" + return_a
```

Once an id is added, it should begin working again. However, it would be even easier if you just stopped using onclick attributes. Give the anchor tag a class of `delete-custom-setting`, then use this (only once, not within an event handler or function.) Also, remove the onclick attribute.

```
$("#customSettingsTableContent").on('click', '.delete-custom-setting', function () {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var siblings = thisRow.siblings();
    thisRow.remove();
    if (siblings.length === 0) {
        $("#customSettingsTableContent").html(...no more content etc...);
    }
});
```

Also note that you may want to be using .append, because otherwise you'll never have more than one row in this section.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
function addCustomSetting() {

  $('.noRecords').remove();
  var staticHtml = '<tr> <th scope="row">' + $('#customSettingsTableContent tr').length + '</th> <td>new name</td><td>new last name</td><td> <a href="#" onclick="removeCustomSetting(event)"> <div class="fa fa-close"></div></a> </td></tr>';

  $('#customSettingsTableContent').append(staticHtml);

}



function removeCustomSetting(event) {
  var t = $('#customSettingsTableContent tr').eq(0).find('th').length;
  event.target.closest('tr').remove(); // you will only need this line of code

  if ($('#customSettingsTableContent tr').length == 1) {
    $('#customSettingsTableContent').append('<tr class="noRecords"> <td colspan="' + t + '">No More Records!</td></tr>')

  }

}
```

```css
a .fa {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
}
a:hover .fa {
  background: #FFC107;
}
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button type="button" onclick="addCustomSetting()" class="btn btn-primary">
  <div class="fa fa-plus"></div>
</button>

<table id="customSettingsTableContent" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>

        <a href="#" onclick="removeCustomSetting(event)">
          <div class="fa fa-close"></div>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>

        <a href="#" onclick="removeCustomSetting(event)">
          <div class="fa fa-close"></div>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>

        <a href="#" onclick="removeCustomSetting(event)">
          <div class="fa fa-close"></div>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

hope this helps..:)